# what's the difference between NSManagedObjectContext reset and rollback?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

The documentation says:

> ```
> - (void)reset
> ```
>
> Returns the receiver to its base state.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this method, you should ensure that you also discard references to any managed objects fetched using the receiver, since they will be invalid afterwards.

---

> ```
> - (void)rollback
> ```
>
> Removes everything from the undo stack, discards all insertions and deletions, and restores updated objects to their last committed values.
>
> #### Discussion
>
> This method does not refetch data from the persistent store or stores.

It seems that after I make some change to my context, calling these two method will do exactly the same thing: discard changes and restore updated objects to their last committed values. So what does `-reset` actually do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The key part is in the quote

> All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten”.

`- (void)reset;` will give you a clean `NSManagedObjectContext` with no objects in it and as the docs state any `NSManagedObject`'s you have around should be discarded as they are no longer valid.

`- (void)rollback` will just restore the `NSManagedObject`'s to their persisted values

Answer (score 14):

`-reset` is different than `-rollback` in that it invalidates any `NSManagedObject`s that have been fetched from the context. Attempting to use those objects can be expected to throw an exception. However `-rollback` simply discards unsaved changes.

Comment: Hi Kevin Ballard, a small question... is there any way to revert back the changes once a managed object context is saved?

Comment: For future readers: accessing reset voided objects does not cause an exception, the just report being a fault. Know from personal experience.