# How can I make multiple calls of NSBatchUpdateRequest within DB transaction so that either all rows is updated or none is updated?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is there a way, to make multiple `NSBatchUpdateRequest` calls executed within a DB transaction, so that either all DB rows is updated or none is updated (When exception thrown)?

The following code illustrate the problem.

---

```
func debug() {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    let backgroundContext = coreDataStack.backgroundContext
    
    backgroundContext.perform {
        let fetchRequest = NSTabInfo.fetchSortedRequest()
        
        do {
            var objectIDs: [NSManagedObjectID] = []
            
            let nsTabInfos = try fetchRequest.execute()
            
            //
            // QUESTION: We are updating multiple rows of data directly in a persistent store.
            // How can we ensure either all rows is updated, or none row is updated is exception
            // happens in between?
            //
            for nsTabInfo in nsTabInfos {
                let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "NSTabInfo")
                batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self == %@", nsTabInfo.objectID)
                batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["name": nsTabInfo.name! + "XXX"]
                batchUpdateRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
                
                let batchUpdateResult = try backgroundContext.execute(batchUpdateRequest) as? NSBatchUpdateResult
                
                guard let batchUpdateResultX = batchUpdateResult else { return }
                guard let managedObjectIDs = batchUpdateResultX.result else { return }

                if let nsManagedObjectIDs = managedObjectIDs as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                    objectIDs.append(contentsOf: nsManagedObjectIDs)
                }
                
                //
                // Simulate some exception
                // We notice the first row is updated & rest of the rows are unchanged.
                // This leaves our data in inconsistent state.
                //
                throw "Custom error!!!"
            }
            
            if !objectIDs.isEmpty {
                let changes = [NSUpdatedObjectsKey : objectIDs]
                coreDataStack.mergeChanges(changes)
            }
            
        } catch {
            backgroundContext.rollback()
            
            error_log(error)
        }
    }
}

class CoreDataStack {
    static let INSTANCE = CoreDataStack()
    
    private init() {
    }
    
    private(set) lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "wenote")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        // So that when backgroundContext write to persistent store, container.viewContext will retrieve update from
        // persistent store.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
    
    private(set) lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return backgroundContext
    }()
    

    func mergeChanges(_ changes: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(
            fromRemoteContextSave: changes,
            into: [persistentContainer.viewContext, backgroundContext]
        )
    }
}
```

---

We write a demo code to illustrate the following

1. Performing `NSBatchUpdateRequest` multiple times within a loop.
2. An exception happens in between.
3. We wishes none of the row in persistent store is updated. However, a row is already updated before the exception thrown.

May I know what technique I can use, which is similar to SQLite transaction feature, so that either all rows is updated, or none of the row is updated when exception happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CoreData.framework` doesn't open up `SQLite` level controls to the user, it provides you `NSManagedObjectContext`.

How does it work in a similar manner?

1. You pull as many objects in many as you need and do your changes on them.
2. When you are done with your changes, you do `context.save()`.
3. In that way, you save all of your changes in one shot.

In all cases, pulling all objects in memory might not be possible or a good idea, so then you need to implement your own solution around how to send all of these changes to disk.

From the [`NSBatchUpdateRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchupdaterequest) docs -

> A request to Core Data to do a batch update of data in a persistent store without loading any data into memory.

When you execute this, you are doing the changes in store that you can't roll back. For a large data-set, you can do following -

1. Say you have to perform a series of updates (5 different steps) on 100k records as an operation.
2. Start in a background thread, pull objects in memory in batches of 1k at a time.
3. You can load 1k objects easily in memory, mutate them - go through all of your changes/steps one by one and save these changes on this batch. If this is successful, you move on to the next batch.
4. In case one intermediate step fails on a batch, you can then use either [`NSManagedObjectContext.rollback()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506942-rollback) or [`NSManagedObjectContext.reset()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506807-reset) depending on your implementation.

[Here's a popular SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319926/whats-the-difference-between-nsmanagedobjectcontext-reset-and-rollback) on the differences between the two in case official docs don't provide enough clarity.