# FetchRequest and reset in SwiftUI View?

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I tried around with reset() of the context and found a strange behavior. I use the property wrapper for the fetch request in the SwiftUI View. When resetting the context why are there still the objects in the list? Does it only reset all objects which aren't saved? But what is the difference to rollback()? While testing I found a strange behavior which could have to do with the Discussion part of the Docs but how should it be handled with the property wrapper, or is it better to use rollback()?

And after clicking the reset button the list doesn't get updated, also there is one persons name setted to nil, which is strange too.

Link to Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FFft.jpg

From Doc:

> *Summary*
>
> Returns the context to its base state. Declaration
>
> func reset()
>
> *Discussion*
>
> All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this
> method, you should ensure that you also discard references to any
> managed objects fetched using the receiver, since they will be invalid
> afterwards.

My Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)]) var persons: FetchedResults<Person>
    
    func saveContext(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{}
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(persons.count)")
            if persons.isEmpty{
                Text("No persons defined")
            }else{
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVStack{
                        ForEach(persons){p in
                            Text(p.name ?? "NO NAME").background(Color.green)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Add Person without save"){
                let p = Person(context: context)
                p.id = UUID()
                p.name = "Test Without save \(persons.count)"
            }
            Button("Add Person with save"){
                let p = Person(context: context)
                p.id = UUID()
                p.name = "Test with save \(persons.count)"
                saveContext()
            }
            Button("reset"){
                context.reset()
            }
            Button("rollback"){
                context.rollback()
            }
            Button("delete All"){
                for p in persons{
                    context.delete(p)
                }
                saveContext()
            }
            Button("save Context"){
                saveContext()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Resetting  the context does not affect the store. The `FetchRequest` is just pulling the objects after reset/rollback. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319926/whats-the-difference-between-nsmanagedobjectcontext-reset-and-rollback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what's the difference between NSManagedObjectContext reset and rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319926/whats-the-difference-between-nsmanagedobjectcontext-reset-and-rollback)

Comment: Is the thing I probably missed in my question, that if I delete an object without saving the context, that rollback() gets the objects back and reset() only would "remove" the added objects? When clicking reset the fetchRequest doesn't pull the objects while rollback does it, why is that?